# Which ones are considered correct in these two sentences? " what I need is/are a car and a house." and " What I like is/are the mountains"

Tags: grammar

Do they always take a singular verb (is) even if they refer to plural nouns?

Comment: Are you considering the car and house as one need or two? Are you considering the mountains as a generic "mountainous region" or is each individual mountain important?

Comment: So you are saying both "is" and "are" are correct depending on our consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that in that exact phrasing of each sentence, only the singular verb works. However, the plural *can* work, depending on interpretation, if the sentences are rephrased.

---

One interpretation of the first example can be paraphrased:

> 1. The ***only thing*** I need ***is*** <sup>a car and a house.</sup>
>    My ***need is*** <sup>a car and a house.</sup>
>    → ✔ What I need ***is*** a car and a house.

As for its other interpretation:

> 2. The ***two things*** I need ***are*** <sup>a car</sup> and <sup>a house.</sup>
>    My ***needs are*** <sup>a car</sup> and <sup>a house.</sup>
>    → ✘ What I need ***are*** a car and a house.

Although the second interpretation breaks each noun into its own need, the specific syntax doesn't allow for *what I need are*. (Note that *what she needs are* would be equally incorrect; it's not the conjugation of the verb at issue here but the syntax around it.)

If you want to express two different needs, you have to actually rephrase the sentence in order to make the plurality of the noun *need* (rather than multiple objects of the verb *need*) obvious.

---

A similar analysis could be done for the second sentence, where you can interpret the mountains as a collective noun or as individual nouns.

However, as with the first sentence, only the following is a specifically correctly phrased sentence:

> What I like ***is*** the mountains.

As before, rephrasing would be required in order to make the plurality of the noun *like* idiomatic.

For instance (although odd):

> The things I like are (each of) those mountains.
>   My likes are (each of) those mountains.

The second of the two sentences might actually sound natural in the context of Facebook or Twitter, where *likes* is commonly used as a plural noun in this sense.

More natural wording would be something like this, which implies individual *likes* although it doesn't make it as explicit:

> I like each of those mountains (individually).